# Use of widget.pack() does not recover forgotten pack widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.8, tkinter-entry

```
import tkinter

top = tkinter.Tk()

top.geometry("800x800")
top.title("Text Editor")

edit = False
name = tkinter.Entry(top)

def editTrue():
    edit = True
    name.pack_forget()

def editFalse():
    edit = False
    name.pack()

menubar = tkinter.Menu(top)
filemenu = tkinter.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=editFalse)
filemenu.add_command(label="Edit", command=editTrue)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
top.config(menu=menubar)

text = tkinter.Text(top, height=800, width=800)


def saveNotes():
    notes = text.get(1.0, "end")

    f = open(name.get() + ".txt", "a")
    f.write(notes)  
    f.close()

button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Save", command=saveNotes)

button.pack()
name.pack()
text.pack()


top.mainloop()
```

This is my code so far, and the problem is, when I call the `widget.pack_forget()` function, it works perfectly well. It hides it and all that stuff. But, when I call the `widget.pack()` again to recover it, it doesn't come up. I don't understand why. I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: When `name.pack()`is called again, `name` will be *packed* below the text box and so it is outside the viewable area of the window because the text box is very very big.

Comment: Ahh, I see. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Make the text box smaller, like `width=80` and `height=20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text box is too big, 800 characters width and 800 lines height.  So when `name` is *removed* (`name.pack_forget()`) and then *shown* again (`name.pack()`), it will be packed below the text box.  Since the text box is too big, `name` is pushed out of the viewable area of the window.

Either making the text box smaller (`width=80, height=40`), or *pack* `name` before the text box using `name.pack(before=text)`.

Answer (score 1):

> when I call the widget.pack() again to recover it, it doesn't come up
> Use `lambda` instead of created functions.

- In line 13, add `lambda` and `pady` in command keyword.
- In line 14, `lambda` in command keyword.
- In line 32, Add pady=10 in `Entry` widget.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter

top = tkinter.Tk()
top.geometry("800x800")
top.title("Text Editor")

edit = False
name = tkinter.Entry(top)


menubar = tkinter.Menu(top)
filemenu = tkinter.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=lambda: name.pack(pady=10))
filemenu.add_command(label="Edit", command=lambda: name.pack_forget())
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
top.config(menu=menubar)

text = tkinter.Text(top, height=40, width=80)


def saveNotes():
    notes = text.get(1.0, "end")

    f = open(name.get() + ".txt", "a")
    f.write(notes)  
    f.close()

button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Save", command=saveNotes)

button.pack()
text.pack()
name.pack(pady=10)
 
top.mainloop()
```

Screenshot: You will see Entry widget hidden and shown at the bottom.

[image]